# How to: Update related (through Regarding field) Lead on Task create/update in MS Dynamics

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

**Scenario**:
A Lead is created. Then, a Task is created related (through Regarding field) to this Lead.
**Question**:
How to update a field (Boolean) on Lead object right after a Task is created/updated? The Lead update should be done basing on some conditions of the Task.
I'm stuck on process of checking if a Task is related to a Lead object or not. Is it even possible in MS Dynamics?

EDIT 1: I was trying to find a solution using Processes. After a comment I'm assuming this is not possible through Processes, but only with js/plugin. Is it so?

Comment: Where are you trying, js or plugin? Share the code you tried

Comment: Man, I was trying to do it via Process/Flow... Now, as I understand, this is only possible via code.  
So, should I create a plugin with code and it should run somehow after Task is created/updated?

Comment: you can do with a workflow, you can use a check condition like "if regarding (lead) contains data"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it via workflow. Add a condition to verify if the regarding is a lead. Then update the lead.

Sorry for the french. In english it should be: Regarding (Lead) - Lead - Contains Data

[image]

[image]